# How to detect slope vs flat across different levels

Tags: python, gradient, trading

How can i write a function that can detect wether a line is sloped or flat at the latest point in time. I have a dataset of cryptocurrency OHLC data and want to detect wether their MA is flat or sloped, how can i do this? thanks in advance!

I have tried doing it via grading decent and min-max normalization to normalize the different pricelevels. However i cant figure out the logic for detecting if something is sloped or not

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].